# Is continuation style implementation of factorial tail call optimized (TCO)?

Tags: javascript, tail-call-optimization

Here are two factorial implementation [from this site](http://matt.might.net/articles/by-example-continuation-passing-style/):

Tail Call Optimized (TCO):

```
function fact(n) {
  return tail_fact(n,1) ;
}

function tail_fact(n,a) {
  if (n == 0)
    return a ;
  else
    return tail_fact(n-1,n*a) ;
}
```

And the one rewritten in continuation style programming (callback):

```
function fact(n,ret) {
  tail_fact(n,1,ret) ;
} 

function tail_fact(n,a,ret) {
  if (n == 0)
    ret(a) ;
  else
    tail_fact(n-1,n*a,ret) ;
}
```

It seems that the tutorial suggest that the second is also TCO, but the last thing the second version returns is `undefined` and its call is not in tail position according to [this tutorial](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_tail-calls.html).

However it also seems that `return` is not used at all here and hence there is no need to create a new frame on stack with the address to return to. So is this what makes the second implemenation TCO?

Comment: Node7 with `--harmony_tailcalls` doesn't consider the second one valid for TCO. [Axel Rauschmayer says no](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_tail-calls.html#_pitfall-solo-function-calls-are-never-in-tail-position), it's not a tail call, because there's an implicit `return undefined;` after it. I'm not sure I buy that logic (but disagreeing with Axel R on fact makes me very nervous); JS differentiates between exiting a function w/o `return` vs. `return;` or `return undefined;`, even though the result of calling them is the same. At some point I'll get out my machete and have at the spec...

Comment: If we could declare the return type of `tail_fact` to be `void` (undefined), we could trivially see that a `return` doesn't change anything (still returns undefined) and that the call is in a tail position. Unfortunately, we don't have static types in JS, so you need to add the `return` explicitly and *hope* that it always returns undefined…

Comment: I guess a clever interpreter could tail-optimise the second version as well - it puts a `return <constant>` after the return location, and when the next stack frame does the same it knows that the return value will be ignored and can avoid the creation of inner stack frames. But surely the ES6 spec does not require this…

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks, how did you find that `Node` _doesn't consider the second one valid for TCO_?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, @Bergi, thanks guys, so for now I can conclude that it's most likely not guaranteed to TCO in `JS` correct?

Comment: @Maximus: By trying it on `fact(1e6, result => console.log(result))` and getting the stack overflow exception. :-) Whereas with your first one, I don't. This is a variation on kangax's test for TCO support [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, clever :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node7 with `--harmony_tailcalls` doesn't consider the second one valid for TCO, but TCO isn't 100% complete in V8 (hence being behind a runtime flag).

Axel Rauschmayer [says no, it's not a tail call](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_tail-calls.html#_pitfall-solo-function-calls-are-never-in-tail-position), because there's an implicit `return undefined`; after it:

> The function call `bar()` in the following code is not in tail position:
>
> ```
> function foo() {
>     bar(); // this is not a tail call in JS
> }
> ```
>
> The reason is that the last action of `foo()` is not the function call `bar()`, it is (implicitly) returning `undefined`. In other words, `foo()` behaves like this:
>
> ```
> function foo() {
>     bar();
>     return undefined;
> }
> ```
>
> Callers can rely on `foo()` always returning `undefined`. If `bar()` were to return a result for `foo()`, due to tail call optimization, then that would change foo’s behavior.

So in other words, at the end of `foo`, we can't just jump to `bar`, because `bar` may issue a `return` with a value other than `undefined`, whereas `foo` doesn't return any value at all (and thus calling it is guaranteed to yield `undefined`). *Something* has to stay behind (at least for now) when we call `bar` to say "but don't return `bar`'s return value." That something is a stack frame.

*In theory*, the JavaScript engine could pass some kind of flag when calling `bar` telling itself to throw away any value `bar` returns, thus allowing TCO in that case, but I don't see anything in the spec that does that.